# how to capture a word with non word character in regex

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression for capturing particular part of a string

```
[Pp]rocess[\s]+(?<proc>[\w-]*|[\/\w-]*)\([\d]*\) killed by signal (?<signame>[\w\s]*)-(?<signum>[\d]+)

eg:Process  tivosh(1426) killed by signal Hangup-1
```

output : 
proc -> tivosh

signame -> Hangup

signum -> 1

In some cases the signame was coming as comibination "Trace/breakpoint trap"

```
eg: process  uploader(2404) killed by signal Trace/breakpoint trap-5
```

Please let me know, how to capture a word+non word character?

Comment: Add `/` to `[\w\s]`  - `(?<signame>[\w\s/]*)`. Or, use lazy dot matching `.*?` - https://regex101.com/r/gL2lG8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[\w\s]*` only matches zero or more word or whitespace characters. Either add more allowed chars into the class, or use a lazy dot pattern - `.*?`:

```
[Pp]rocess\s+(?<proc>.*?)\(\d*\) killed by signal (?<signame>.*?)-(?<signum>\d+)
                     ^^^                                     ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aY5nL5/1)

The lazy dot pattern will match as few characters other than a newline as possible up to the first `-` followed with 1 or more digits (i.e. the first match for `-(?<signum>\d+)`). Same with `(?<proc>.*?)` - it will match as few any chars other than a newline up to the first `(<digits_here_0_or_more>)`.

Also, there is no point in wrapping single shorthand character classes with character classes (brackets): `[\s]*` = `\s*`.

Comment: Is there a way to accept any non-word character other than ".*?" ? Sometimes the word may also come as hello::hai

Comment: The point is that a non-word is matched with `\W`. Your character class is `[\w\s]` and it matches any word char with `\w`. If you write `[\w\W]` it will match *any* character there is, basically, it is a DOTALL version of `.` that matches any char including a newline. Now, what is your problem with `.*?`? **See https://regex101.com/r/xJ1oF3/2**

Comment: Just to know ... when i tried using [\w\W] i am facing a problem

[Pp]rocess[\s]+(?<proc>[\w\W-]*)\([\d]*\) killed by signal (?<signame>.*?)-(?<signum>[\d]+)

if the input  given

process  uploader dfgfdg(2404) killed by signal Trace/breakpoint trap-5 
process  uploader dfgfdg(2404) killed by signal Trace/breakpoint trap-5 

then the output

proc uploader dfgfdg(2404) killed by signal Trace/breakpoint trap-5 
process uploader dfgfdg
signame Trace/breakpoint trap
signum 5

Comment: If the signame can contain `-`+`digit`, you need to try `.*` instead of `.*?`. Else, add a `$` after `(?<signum>\d+)`. Why do you use `[\w\W-]*`? First, the `-` makes no sense inside that class, second, there must be a `?` after `*` to make it lazy, or it will grab too much. Replace `[\w\W-]*` with `.*?`. And do not use `[\d]`, use `\d`.

Comment: * means Zero or more of pattern  and ? means Zero or one matches of the pattern. Then combination of both *? stands for what?

Comment: @sireesha: That is wrong, `?` (greedy, 1 or 0), `*` (greedy, 0 or more, as many as possible) and `*?`(lazy, 0 or more, as few as possible) are 3 **different** quantifiers. See [*Quantifier Cheatsheet*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet).

Comment: i have a regular expression [\w\W-]*? . How to make sure that it should not capture a word with parenthesis "( )"  eg: (null)

Comment: You mean you want to restrict this class? Depends on the regex flavor. If it is .NET, use `[\w\W-[()]]*?`

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to capture any word, space, no character.

```
[\w\s\W]
```